# Prevent print -P from substituting environment variable

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, prompt

I am using [prompt pure](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure) as my prompt in zsh. Internally it uses `print -Pn ...` to print out the current directory. For some reason, if I have an environment variable set that matches the beginning of the current directory, that environment variable name will be substituted into the output.

For example,

```
> export SOME_DIR=/home/bschlenk/some/path
> cd ~/some/path/deeper/nested/path
> print -Pn %~
~SOME_DIR/deeper/nested/path
```

How do I prevent it from substituting random environment variables into the path that happen to match? I want it to print out the current path, with `/home/bschlenk` substituted with `~`, but no other substitutions.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior with a fairly stock zsh. Perhaps there's additional processing brought in somewhere?

Comment: do you have `$functions[zsh_directory_name]` or `$zsh_directory_name_functions` set by something?

Comment: `echo $functions[zsh_directory_name]` prints nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation of `%~`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state):

> if it has a named directory as its prefix, that part is replaced by a `~` followed by the name of the directory, but only if the result is shorter than the full path

A reference follows to [dynamic](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Dynamic-named-directories) and [static](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories) named directories. What you're seeing is a static named directory

> They may also be defined if the text after the `~` is the name of a string shell parameter whose value begins with a `/`.

So if the value of the variable `SOME_DIR` is `/home/bschlenk/some/path` then `~SOME_DIR` is a static named directory whose value is `/home/bschlenk/some/path`. The prompt expansion `%~` sees `/home/bschlenk/some/path` and abbreviates it to `~SOME_DIR`.

But that's not the whole story. In fact, the abbreviation only happens if `SOME_DIR` has been “activated” by the use of `~SOME_DIR`. This is documented under the [option `auto_name_dirs`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-directories_002c-named), which removes the need for prior activation, but defaults off.

> Any parameter that is set to the absolute name of a directory immediately becomes a name for that directory, that will be used by the `%~` and related prompt sequences, and will be available when completion is performed on a word starting with `~`. (Otherwise, the parameter must be used in the form `~param` first.)

A parameter that is activated for `%~` substitution (and completion after `~`) shows up as an entry in the [named directory hash table](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-hash-1) which you can list with `hash -d`.

We've put the pieces together to understand what's going on. How can you solve your problem? It depends what caused `SOME_DIR` to be activated.

If you have the option `auto_name_dirs` turned on, then obviously you should turn it off.

If you've used `~SOME_DIR` previously, you can deactivate it with

```
unhash -d SOME_DIR
```

This is not permanent: it'll pop up again if you use `~SOME_DIR` again. But given that you can use `$SOME_DIR` wherever you can use `~SOME_DIR`, `~SOME_DIR` is not a very useful feature.

If you can't get rid of what makes `SOME_DIR` a named directory and you want to abbreviate the current directory with nothing but `$HOME` → `~`, you can implement this transformation manually.

```
if [[ $PWD = $HOME ]]; then
  HPWD=\~
elif [[ $PWD = $HOME/* ]]; then
  HPWD=\~/${PWD#$HOME/}
else
  HPWD=$PWD
fi
```

and then use `print -rn $HPWD` instead of `print -Pn %~`.

If you can't prevent `SOME_DIR` from becoming a named directory and you can't change the code that uses `%~`, it gets trickier. You can empty the directory hash table with `hash -r`, but there's no way to make this local to a function (only to a subshell).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! `auto_name_dirs` was set, probably by a script I'm sourcing in my .zshrc file. I added an `unsetopt AUTO_NAME_DIRS` right afterwards, and now `%~` is only replacing `$HOME`.